# How to negate whole words in regex

Tags: .net, regex

I used regular expression a little bit already but now I've stumbled upon a situation, where I don't really know how to do it, and all the online tutorials I read didn't cover my situation.
The problem reads quite easy to solve, and it is probably easy to solve, but I didn't find a solution yet.

I need to parse a string, that is composed of short strings combined with the boolean operators AND, OR and NOT, brackets are allowed, whitespaces shouldn't matter, case insensitive.

For instance

```
xxxx AND  (yyyy or zzzz) and not  qqqq
```

Right now I'd like to find all the strings, that have a NOT infront of it. For that I created this regex pattern

```
"NOT\s+[\w]+"
```

(The literal NOT followed by at least one whitespace, followed by at least one letter/digit.)

This would give me "not  qqqq" in the above example.

But, if the user happens to write

```
xxxx AND  (yyyy or zzzz) and not not  qqqq
```

which is a valid string, then my pattern would give me "not not" instead of "not  qqqq".

So I need a regex pattern that would give me "literal word NOT followed by whitespace followed by any string but NOT followed by whitespace (or string end)".

I know how to negate single characters, but I didn't find any working examples that negate whole words, at least not when I test it in regexstorm.net

I use .NET.

Comment: I'll say that the correct way to analyze it is to capture the whole *not not qqqq*, otherwise you have a dangling *not* somewhere

Comment: And note that you could perhaps  have aaa *xxx and not (yyy or zzz)*

Comment: Yes, I know, I'd like to capture the terms one by one and replace them with placeholders, until I only have simple terms left. So, when the string is "not not qqqq" I'd capture "not qqqq" first and replace it with a place holder, giving me "not <placeholder>", after that the next matching would give me "not <placeholder>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a case insensitive match, you could use

```
\bNOT\s+(?!NOT\b)\w+
```

- `\bNOT\s+` A word boundary, match NOT and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?!NOT\b)` Negativelookahead, assert that `NOT` is not at the right
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbNOT%5cs%2b%28%3f!NOT%5cb%29%5cw%2b&i=xxxx+AND++%28yyyy+or+zzzz%29+and+not++qqqq%0d%0axxxx+AND++%28yyyy+or+zzzz%29+and+not+not++qqqq%0d%0a&o=i)